# Getting x coordinate of View after animation cancel

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm using animation to move a circle left and right. I use this code to stop the circle where it's at if you click a button...

```
circleOne.clearAnimation();
moveOne.cancel();
```

This works, but I want to get the x-coordinate of the view. The problem is, it always returns the same number no matter where it's at on the screen. I think it's returning the x-coordinate of where it was originally at on the screen before it was animated. How can I get the x-coordinate after it has stopped?

Comment: I think u use view animation ? If u use it u dont get animation cordinates u need to use ObjectAnimator.

Comment: That's what I'm using.

Comment: what is the exact parameter that you're animating? is it `translation`?

Comment: Yes, translationX @blipinsk